# How to populate a LinearLayout with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, simplecursoradapter

In my layout, I have some textView with information about the model, and a list:
[image: Layout]

The IDE warns not to put a ListView inside a ScrollView (obviously this will cause a difficulty in using the scroll)

Then I put a LinearLayout.

Can I still use SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a LinearLayout? How?
If not possible use it, how to populate view?

Comment: listview by itself will scroll. so why do you need a listview inside a scroll view? You can set the adapter to listview. it is better you use SimpleCursorAdapter  with listview

Comment: @Raghunandan I was using listView, precisely because the SimpleCursorAdapter. But as there were problems with the scroll, I changed and put a LinearLayout

Comment: what was the problem with the scroll?

Comment: The top (labels) can be very large, larger than the screen. So I need a ScrollView. The problem of placing the list inside the scroll .. is left with two scrolls

Comment: Really? I did it. And now? I can still use the SimpleCursorAdapter? (This is the original question)